# ${stacktrace} in log4net.config just writes stacktrace in the log file

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to have the stacktrace where the log function is called written to the log file.

I'm using Log4Net 1.2.10.0 and C# .NET 4.0 (I can't change any of these)

the logging is called using

```
private static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(global::System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Info("Show the stacktrace here");
```

The log4net.config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">

  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\Application1\Application1.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=" yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601}|[%thread]|%-5level|%message|%stacktrace{5}%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The log file looks like this

> 2017-07-04 11:18:12,206|[8]|INFO
>   |Show the stacktrace here|stacktrace{5}

So instead of showing the actual stack trace I get the word 'stacktrace{5}'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your exception instance, like below

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // the form that takes two args has an exception as second, prints trace...
    _log.Error("My custom message", ex);
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know where you put this line? log.Info("Show the stacktrace here");

Comment: In one of the functions of a Winform program. I also have a larger program that uses multiple assembly's and classes and where the log.info is called in varius methods. I never get any stacktrace just the work stacktrace

Comment: Can you try to configure your Appender with IgnoresException = "False"? http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.LayoutSkeleton.IgnoresException.html

Comment: I have now tried and failed. So I made a copy of the program, changed the version of log4net to the NuGet one and now everything works! Seems like stacktrace doesn't exist in version 1.2.10.0! Unfortunately this is part of larger system and I can't upgrade log4net. Will run some debugging with the new version and maybe I can figure out where my thread handling goes astray...